# Magento 2 InsertForm component in to the UI form component

Tags: magento2.3, admin, uicomponent, ui-form

I would like to add form same as like admin customer edit **Add new address** form. So i have added **InsertForm** component inside the customer edit form using [this reference link](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/ui_comp_guide/components/ui-insertform.html)

A form is displaying fine but save, cancel and back button are not displaying in form

can anybody have idea why button is not displaying in form.

Answer (score 3):

The documentation regarding the InsertForm component is somewhat lacking. To display the inserted forms buttons, use `mui/index/render_handle` rather than `mui/index/render` for the `<renderUrl>` param.

Here's an example that I have recently used.

```
<!-- component is not required. this form was very similar and benefits from the customer insert-form -->
    <insertForm name="update_contact_address_form_loader" component="Magento_Customer/js/form/components/insert-form">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <!-- The name of the inserted forms data provider : the first half of the inserted forms provider param -->
                <item name="addressListingProvider" xsi:type="string">ns = example_contacts_addresses_listing, index = example_contacts_addresses_listing</item>
                <!-- parentName (if using modal) -->
                <item name="addressModalProvider" xsi:type="string">${ $.parentName }</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <settings>
            <formSubmitType>ajax</formSubmitType>
            <!-- note the renderUrl is 'render_handle' rather than just 'render' this is required for rendering buttons -->
            <renderUrl path="mui/index/render_handle">
                <!-- The handle name is the same as the layout name. Example: view/adminhtml/layout/example_contacts_addresses_edit.xml -->
                <param name="handle">example_contacts_addresses_edit</param>
                <!-- show buttons from inserted form -->
                <param name="buttons">1</param>
            </renderUrl>
            <loading>false</loading>
            <toolbarContainer>${ $.parentName }</toolbarContainer>
            <!-- The data provider of the inserted form : the second half of the inserted forms provider param -->
            <externalProvider>${ $.ns }.addresses_form_data_source</externalProvider>
            <!-- The name of the inserted ui component form -->
            <ns>example_contacts_addresses_form</ns>
            <exports>
                <!-- for this particular form, parent_id is a foreign key that references the entity_id of the contact -->
                <link name="parentId">${ $.externalProvider }:data.parent_id</link>
            </exports>
            <imports>
                <link name="parentId">${ $.provider}:data.entity_id</link>
            </imports>
        </settings>
    </insertForm>
```

Magento's Customer Module is a helpful resource. Check out the [customer_form.xml](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.4/app/code/Magento/Customer/view/base/ui_component/customer_form.xml#L480-#L506) for

Comment: how can I add required to InsertForm component ?